# query entity with condition on ManyToMany relation

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two Entites

```
    @Entity 
    public Report() 

@Id
@Column(name = "REPORT_ID")
private long id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
      name="reports_projects",
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="report_id", referencedColumnName="REPORT_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="PROJECT_ID")})
private List<Project> projects;
```

second is:

```
    @Entity(name = "projects")
    public class Project 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
// seems like spring's jpa has issue hanlde "_" between the words
private long id;

@Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
private String code;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
private String description;

@Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
private Date creationDate;
```

i'm tring to query reports by projects.code 
tried few stuff like

```
    @Query("select reports from org.jpp.domain.quicksearch.ReportQS reports inner join   reports.projects p  where p.code in :code")
```

And

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<QuickSearchResult> query = cb.createQuery(QuickSearchResult.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();

EntityType<ReportQS> ReportQSMetaModel = m.entity(ReportQS.class);

Root<ReportQS> reportsQS = query.from(ReportQS.class);
Root<Project> projects = query.from(Project.class);
Join<ReportQS, Project> joinReportsProjects =  reportsQS.join("projects");
Predicate condition = cb.equal(projects.get("code"),"gnrl");
query.select(reportsQS).where(condition);

TypedQuery<QuickSearchResult> q = em.createQuery(query);
```

I get empty result for both of the queries
Any idea how to get this to work ?

Thanks in advance,
Oak

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
String query = "select r from ReportQS r join r.projects p where p.code = :code";
List<ReportQS> reports = em.createQuery(query,ReportQS.class).setParameter("code","grnl").getResultList();
```

Make sure that ReportQS is name of entity class (in your sample code you have different class name and different entity name used in query).

Comment: thanks for reply. Unfortunately I still get an empty result. Any other solution(s)?

Comment: My mistake! It works. the problem was that i used the wrong referencedColumnName in project. thanks!